# Filter mongoengine query

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have some trouble filtering on a query and I do not know why. All my other filters are working just fine.

First of all I have an mongoDB collection with data looking like this:

```
_id: generated
title: stringfield
date: Datefield
Responses: EmbeddedDocument 
    user: ReferenceField
    help: BooleanField
```

Current responses stored in DB (all with the same user):

- 2 times with Responses.help = False
- 2 times with Responses.help = True

Now I want to know how many times a user has responded to questions:

```
@queryset_manager
def responses_user(doc_cls, queryset):
    return queryset.filter(responses__user=current_user.id).count
```

The query above works, it gives back the correct amount of responses(4). Now I want to add a filter to it, because I want to know how many times te user responded with True. So the query becomes:

```
@queryset_manager
def responses_user(doc_cls, queryset):
    return queryset.filter(responses__user=current_user.id, responses__help=True).count
```

Now I get a result I do not understand. Its gives me back 3. It should be 2. I do not understand two things about this:

1. Why does it give back 3? Thats a really odd number
2. Why doesn't my query work?

FYI, the way I do the call is :

```
responses = Questions.responses_user()
```

So this can not be the problem I think

Comment: Did you modify the model after documents started to be inserted? Also check the raw format of your documents from a mongo shell, maybe you ll be able to find the problem

Comment: It seems like deleting the entire questions collection and creating new questions did the trick. I was unable to find what change made this query mallfunction. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I can use [raw_queries](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#raw-queries) to use with nested field like this:

```
queryset.filter(
  __raw__= {'responses.user': current_user.id, 'responses.help' = True}
).count
```

Comment: This should be the exact same as how mongoengine should translate: 
`.filter(responses__user=current_user.id, responses__help=True)` to pymongo so I'd be surprised that it fixes the problem

Comment: This makes the request more explicit. The query in question itself should work if fields like id are not confused. As far as I know the names "help", "user" are not system, but I usually reinsure. This is the only idea that comes to my mind.